# Border styles in p:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to apply a dotted border to PF 5.0 [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) as follows.

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="panelgrid-dotted-border">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2">
                <h:outputText value="Shipping Address"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>

    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width: 200px;">
            <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 200px;">
            <h:outputText id="firstName" value="First Name"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel for="middleName" value="Middle Name" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="middleName" value="Middle Name"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="lastName" value="Last Name"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel for="address1" value="First Address" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column rowspan="8" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <h:outputText id="address1" styleClass="address" value="First Address"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column><h:outputText value="&#160;" /></p:column></p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

The CSS class :

```css
.panelgrid-dotted-border.ui-panelgrid tr, .panelgrid-dotted-border.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border-top : 1px dotted #000;
    border-right : 1px dotted #000;
    border-bottom : 1px dotted #000;
    border-left : 1px dotted #000;
}
```

The dotted border is not correctly applied to columns and rows which are split over rows and columns respectively as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

The dotted border is applied incorrectly to the rows which are spanned through the first address row and to the column which is spanned through the header of the grid.

How to apply the dotted border correctly?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps you zoomed out a bit in your browser with e.g. Ctrl+Scollwheel? Press Ctrl+0 to reset the zoom. Otherwise, tell browser make/version. Might as well just be a browser rendering bug.

Comment: I did ctrl+0 but it made no difference. Tried to run on other browsers and it worked fine. This happens only on Google Chrome (`37.0.2062.124 m`).

Comment: I've here 37.0.2062.103 m for Windows (on a mobile Radeon GPU) and, indeed, only the border above "First Name" appears solid, however the vertical border between cells appear fine but it becomes solid exactly as on your screenshot when I zoom out one step. At least, the CSS is fine. You might want to consider to switch from `dotted` to `dashed`. Chrome renders it better. Or perhaps `solid` with a lighter color.

Comment: On Google Chrome, a dotted border appears right on 90% zoom. Perhaps, I will consider a dashed border or a solid border with a lighter colour. Do you want to answer it or the question makes no sense and may be liable for deletion? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've faced this problem before and it looks like a bug to me ([for example](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157106)). I'll offer you some workarounds if you really want to keep it "dotted" and you can play with them and choose something similar:

**First (try this):**

```
.panelgrid-dotted-border{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px dotted #929292;
}
.panelgrid-dotted-border.ui-panelgrid tr, .panelgrid-dotted-border.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: 1px dotted #929292;
}
```

You force borders to separate but give them 0 space. This way you can have dots, but double number of dots together. If you also add a lighter color the double number of dots look fine.

**Second:**

```
.panelgrid-dotted-border{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

You can just separate the borders. Looks good too!

**Third:**

```
.panelgrid-dotted-border.ui-panelgrid {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Play with the width of the table, wider renders perfecly for me.

None of them are a real solution but maybe they can help you.

Comment: I considered a solid border with a lighter colour that looks better (at least to me) than a dotted border. Thanks :)

Comment: I agree, and you also play safer that way :), you're welcome.